# RSelenium: Try if findElement succeeds, then click on it, error: "object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, try-catch, rvest, rselenium, r-s4

I'm scraping https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/sabo20 with `RSelenium`.

I want to click on each `li` that have texts ending with the years `2015` until `2021`. The xpath works well.

A year (e.g. `2021`) might be missing, which is why I use a `try()`-approach.

```
  URL <- "https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/sabo20"

  # open RSelenium
  rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "90.0.4430.24", port = 4546L, verbose = F)

  remDr <- rD[["client"]]
  remDr$navigate(URL)
  Sys.sleep(4)

  for (yyyy in c(2015:2021)) {
    error <- "Error : \t Summary: NoSuchElement\n \t Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.\n \t class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException\n\t Further Details: run errorDetails method\n"

    volumes <- try(unlist(
      remDr$findElement(
        using = "xpath",
        paste0(
          "//li[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('",
          yyyy,
          "') +1) = '",
          yyyy,
          "']/div"
        )
      )
    ))
    
      if(volumes[1] == error)
        break;
    
    volumes$clickElement()
  }
```

Unfortunately, `if(volumes[1] == error)` leads to an error if `findElement()` had succeeded:

**Error in volumes[1] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable**

How then can I check whether `remDr$findElement()` succeeded before I `clickElement()` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be `trycatch`

Below an example.

```
URL <- "https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/sabo20"

# open RSelenium
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "90.0.4430.24", port = 4546L, verbose = F)

remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(URL)
Sys.sleep(4)

for (yyyy in c(1983:2021)) {
tryCatch(expr = {   
  volumes <- unlist(
    remDr$findElement(
      using = "xpath",
      paste0(
        "//li[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('",
        yyyy,
        "') +1) = '",
        yyyy,
        "']/div"
      )
    )
  )
  volumes$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(4)
  },
  error =function(e){          
    message("if you want you can break, but it not necessary")
  })
}
```